# Can I run Blueman from Command Line

Tags: command-line, bluetooth, blueman

Is it possible to use the command line to connect to a recent connection of the blueman-manager?

The applet has the connection I need saved under "recent connections". Instead of using the mouse to select the connection, I would very much like to use the command line (due to the setup of the computer)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

Run in the terminal:

```
blueman-manager
```

When the connections list appears you may use `TAB` button and arrow keys to navigate.

Comment: That would certainly work, thank you. But are there any application options for "blue-manager" to accomplish this in one shot?

Comment: Try add ` --help` after the command.